# Need help on Python regarding lists and extracting numbers.

Tags: python

I am stuck yet again on a code. 
I have a file called players.txt that looks like this:

```
Brad Ebert,471
Michael Johnson,459
Brodie Smith,466
Kade Simpson,466
Luke Shuey,465
Justin Westhoff,464
```

and my code looks like this:

```
items = open('players.txt')
items = [i.split(',', 1)[1] for i in items]
player = input('Player: ')
while player != ' ':
  player = input('Player: ')
  for person in player:
    result = sum(items[person]) for person in player) 
    print (result)
```

How do I make it so that when I input Player names, I get the following result? (The code is supposed to stop on a blank input):

```
Player: Justin Westhoff
Player: Brodie Smith
Player: Brad Ebert
Player: 
Total score for team: 1401
```

Comment: What problems are you having?

Comment: One thing might be `!= ' '`, maybe you mean `!= ''` (empty string)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @pbible said, using a dict is the best way. Here's my solution:

```
items = open('players.txt')
myDict = dict()
for i in items:
    myKey, myVal = i.split(',')
    myDict[myKey.lower()] = int(myVal)

result = 0
while True:
    player = input('Player: ')
    if player = '':
        break
    elif myDict.get(player.lower()):
        result += myDict[player]
    else:
        print('Player not found')

print('Total score for team: ' + str(result))
```

Comment: +1 I like this answer. Only suggestions would be to only break if input is empty. Requiring the user to enter a matching name may be putting too much faith in the user to get it right every time.

Comment: I tried your code, and it seems to work quite well, but when I print for the result, it only prints the value for the last player inputted? Is this an error on my side?

Comment: Nice, I like the changes. This definitely makes it easier on the user.

Answer (score 0):

First try setting up a dictionary like this:

This is output from interactive python

```
>>> f = open('players.txt')
>>> playerMap = {}
>>> for line in f:
...   line = line.strip()
...   parts = line.split(",")
...   playerMap[parts[0]] = int(parts[1])
... 
>>> playerMap
{'Michael Johnson': 459, 'Justin Westhoff': 464, 'Luke Shuey': 465, 'Kade Simpson': 466, 'Brad Ebert': 471, 'Brodie Smith': 466}
>>>
```

Then check if the player string is a key in your playerMap

```
result = 0
while player != '':
  if player in playerMap:
    result += playerMap[player]
  #If player is empty now no work will be done
  player = input('Player: ')
#print result when you are done
print(result)
```

Comment: Yours seems to be the best one so far, but how do I convert to int to make it so that this works:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "program.py", line 6, in <module>
    result = sum(items[person] for person in player) 
  File "program.py", line 6, in <genexpr>
    result = sum(items[person] for person in player) 
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

Comment: You should make a dictionary that maps a name to int. Then check if the input is in the dictionary.